# Imagem de Url travando aplicativo Delphi mobile

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

sou inciante em delphi mobile e estou com a seguinte situação:
tenho 3 listview que recebe dados via rest de um site PHP

usando restCliente, RestREquest e restResponse...
os dados recebe certim, popula alistvew tudo corretamente, compila também tudo normal.... o problema vem a seguir.....

no rest tem um campo imagem (jpg,png) somente a url da imagem,
uso esta função para converter a imagem em Bitmap

```
function TfrmPrincipal.LerImage(url: string): TBitmap;
 var
 strm : TmemoryStream;
 begin
    strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
          http.Get(url,strm);
          strm.Position := 0;
          Result  := TBitmap.Create;
          result.Width := 100;
          result.Height := 50;
          result.LoadFromStream(strm);

    finally
      strm.Free;
    end;
 end;
```

porem quando coloco na listview esta imagem o aplicativo trava (para de responder..... uso desta forma no listview

```
procedure TFrmprincipal.ExecuteREST(aList: TListview; aArray: string);
var
  obj : TjsonObject;
  Item : TlistviewItem;
  lResult : TjsonArray;
   strm : TMemoryStream;

begin
  lResult := REST(aArray);
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
   for i:= 0 to lresult.Count-1 do
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure()
      begin
         obj            := lResult.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
         Item           := aList.Items.Add;
         item.text      := obj.GetValue('nome').Value;
         if (obj.GetValue('logo').ToString <> 'null') then
             Item.bitmap := LerImage(''+PathUrl+'/images/empresas/'+obj.GetValue('logo').Value)
          else
          Item.bitmap := LerImage(''+PathUrl+'/images/empresas/semimagem.png');
      end);
     end
   end).Start;

end;
```

O detalhe é se coloco apenas 2 listview funciona corretamente... mas se colocar um botão pra puxar o outro listview trava também.....
Ja tentei de várias formas, com TTask, com Thread e sem Thread, com synchronize, com Queue e nada.....

alguem me dá uma luz como resolver isso??

Comment: De facto à primeira vista esta a fazer tudo certo.... nenhuma pista sobre a linha exata onde trava?

Comment: se eu colocar imagem item.bitmap, essa imagem vem de um site... se coloco os tres listview trava, se coloca dois ou um, abre normal.

Answer (score 0):

E se mudar o conceito?

Ao invés de criar uma thread para fazer TUDO, criar uma thread para cada necessidade?

Algo como:

```
  for i := 0 to Pred(lResult.Count) do
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure
          begin
            obj := lResult.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
            Item := aList.Items.Add;
            Item.text := obj.GetValue('nome').Value;

            if (obj.GetValue('logo').ToString <> 'null') then
              Item.bitmap := LerImage('' + PathUrl + '/images/empresas/' + obj.GetValue('logo').Value)
            else
              Item.bitmap := LerImage('' + PathUrl + '/images/empresas/semimagem.png');
          end);
      end).Start;
  end;
```

Apenas tirei a repetição de dentro da thread, dessa forma cada imagem será renderizada de forma independente.

Uma outra modificação que é necessário é na função `LerImage`. Ao invés de ser apenas um `try finally` considere utilizar um `try except`, pois, se trata de uma conexão com a internet, por algum motivo ocorrer uma falha a aplicação não vai parar.

Edit.

Talvez ainda possa retirar o `TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,...` vale testar se não resolver com a mudança proposta.

Edit².

Agora você precisa mudar a propriedade do listview para exibir imagens.
Botão direito nele e habilite o `Design Mode` e mude a propriedade `Appearance`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por padrão esta definido como `ListItem`, basta mudar para `ImageListItem` e rodar.

Comment: Fiz tudo isso... colocando a thread como sugeriu, não trava, masss as listview fica toda em branco, não aparece nada.
coloquei um showmessage no array, e os dados retorna do rest normal.

Comment: @GeraldoLacerda Da uma olhada na segunda edição da resposta. Faltava modificar a propriedade de aparência do ListView

Comment: o listview esta tudo correto, pois se colocar dois listview funciona certo, o detalhe é só quando coloco 3 listview... ex: listviewEmpresas e listviewdestaques, assim abre certim não trava nem nada. AGORA se acrescento o listviewCategorias, aí trava tudo nem sai da tela de abertura